# Angularjs Message box showns only one textbox irrespective of the user selected

Tags: css, angularjs

Am trying to build a multi-messaging chatbox using angularjs. Within the Angularjs array, I have four users.

**Here is my issue:**

The application shows only just one popup box irrespective of the user clicked as can be seen in the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

**Here is what am trying to achieve**

what I want is something like facebook multi-chat message box. That is if I select multiple user,
Eg. Two users, am supposed to be seeing two popup messagebox that corresponds to those users, if select three users
am supposed to being seeing three users popup box and so on...

**Here is the code so far**

```
<!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.arr= [
        {name:"user1"},
        {name:"user2"},
        {name:"user3"},
        {name:"user4"}
        ];

//pop div
 $scope.popIt = function(id){
          $scope.popId = ($scope.popId==id)?-1:id;
        }

//hide/unhide div partly working
 $scope.IsVisible = false;
        $scope.ShowHide = function(id){
            $scope.IsVisible = ($scope.IsVisible = true)?-1:id;
        }


    });

</script>

<style>


.sidebar {
     width: 250px;
     position: fixed;
     height: 100%;
     right: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     padding-top: 200px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
text-align:bottom;
}



.contact_box{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-5px;
    width:250px;
      // height:100px;
    background:black;
        color:white;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
          bottom: 0px;
 right: 270px;
display: inline-block;
}

</style>


    </head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='ret in arr track by $index'>

        <div ng-click="popIt($index)"  >
 {{ret.name}}</div>




<div ng-if="popId==$index" class="contact_box">

<button style="float:right" ng-click="popIt($index)">Close</button>
<button style="float:left" ng-click="ShowHide()">hide/unhide</button>
<br>


<div  style="height:100px;" ng-hide="IsVisible">

          <b>Username:</b> {{ret.name}}
<br>Message .........<br>
<br>Message .........<br>
<br>Message .........<br>
<br>Message .........<br>
<br>Message .........<br>
<br>Message .........<br>

</div>

</div>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

</body>



</html>
```

**Updated Section:**

Thanks Sir **Akber Iqbal**, Your solution is working great.
One more thing that is bordering me though its out of my post.
My hide/unhide button only hide or minimize just one messagebox.
 If I try to hide another popup box it will open the first popup box already hidden.

it seems the id of the **hide/unhide button** is conflicting as per code
below

```
//hideUnhide message box
 $scope.hideUnhideIt = function(id){
          $scope.hideUnhideId = ($scope.hideUnhideId==id)?-1:id;
        }
```

[image: screenshot]

**Here is how I added the hide/unhide message box in your solution**

```
<!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
        <title></title>

<style>
.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  text-align: bottom;
}

.mainArea {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: 0%
}

.contact_box {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 250px;
  // height:auto;
  background: black;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  //right: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.arr = [{
      name: "user1",
      popStatus: false
    },
    {
      name: "user2",
      popStatus: false
    },
    {
      name: "user3",
      popStatus: false
    },
    {
      name: "user4",
      popStatus: false
    }
  ];

//hideUnhide message box
 $scope.hideUnhideIt = function(id){
          $scope.hideUnhideId = ($scope.hideUnhideId==id)?-1:id;
        }


  //pop div
  $scope.popIt = function(id) {
    if ($scope.arr[id].popStatus == true) {
      $scope.arr[id].popStatus = false
    } else {
      $scope.arr[id].popStatus = true;
    }
  }


});


</script>
    </head>
<body>


<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='ret in arr track by $index'>

        <div ng-click="popIt($index)">
          {{ret.name}} <!-- visible:{{ret.popStatus}} --><br><br>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class='mainArea'>
    <ng-controller ng-repeat='ret in arr track by $index'>
      <div ng-if="ret.popStatus == true" class="contact_box">
        <button style="float:right" ng-click="popIt($index)">Close</button>
         <button style="float:left" ng-click="hideUnhideIt($parent.$index)">hide/unhide</button>
        <br>
        <div ng-if="hideUnhideId!=$index" style="height:auto;">

          <b>Username:</b> {{ret.name}}
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-controller>
  </div>
</div>



</body>



</html>
```

Comment: You appear to be using a single scope variable - `popId` - to store the $index of the visible item. Given you have `ng-if="popId==$index"` - then you will only ever have a single visible item.

Comment: Can you provide the html code?

Comment: All te codes are there both html and angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to keep a score of visibility against each item in the array; plus did some css stuff so that the chat boxes don't overlap each other; open the snippet in full page so that you can see the effects of relative and fixed positioning;

**UPDATE**: in light of Feedback by Nancy, the hide/unhide button is now toggling against each individual chat window also

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.arr = [
    {      name: "user1",      popStatus: false,      hideBox: false    },
    {      name: "user2",      popStatus: false,      hideBox: false    },
    {      name: "user3",      popStatus: false,      hideBox: false    },
    {      name: "user4",      popStatus: false,      hideBox: false    }
  ];

  //pop div
  $scope.popIt = function(id) {
    if ($scope.arr[id].popStatus == true) {
      $scope.arr[id].popStatus = false
    } else {
      $scope.arr[id].popStatus = true;
    }
  }

  //hideUnhide message box
  $scope.hideUnhideIt = function(id) {
    ($scope.arr[id].hideBox == true) ? $scope.arr[id].hideBox = false: $scope.arr[id].hideBox = true;
  }

});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  text-align: bottom;
}

.mainArea {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: 0%
}

.contact_box {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 250px;
  // height:auto;
  background: black;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  //right: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='ret in arr track by $index'>
        <div ng-click="popIt($index)">
          {{ret.name}}
          <!--           hide:{{ret.hideBox}}          -->
          <br><br>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class='mainArea'>
    <ng-controller ng-repeat='ret in arr track by $index'>
      <div ng-if="ret.popStatus == true" class="contact_box">
        <button style="float:right" ng-click="popIt($index)">Close</button>
        <button style="float:left" ng-click="hideUnhideIt($parent.$index)">hide/unhide</button>
        <br>
        <div ng-if="!ret.hideBox" style="height:auto;">

          <b>Username:</b> {{ret.name}}
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
          <br>Message .........<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-controller>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Akber Iqbal, Your solution is working great. God bless You...

One more thing that is bordering me though its out of my post.
My hide/unhide button only hide or minimize just one messagebox.
 If I try to hide another popup box it will open the first popup box already hidden.

it seems the id of the hide/unhide bitton is conflicting.
please can you see my Updated Section of my post to see if there is anything you can do to help me futher.

Between thanks for your wonderful contributions so far. Hoping to hear from you soonest..

Comment: Hi @NancyMooree, Hope that you are doing good - Kindly check the updated code and let me know if there is anything, have a nice day

Comment: Thanks alot Sir Akber Iqbal. You are the best

Comment: Hi, Sir Akber Iqbal. I have one last wish from you. please can you have a look at the code here to see if there is anything you can on it .Thanks for all your contributions so far. here is the stackoverflow link of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862669/how-to-persist-open-div-box-using-angularjs